# Quickbooks invalid social security number error

Tags: quickbooks

One of my clients is using Quickbooks 2018 desktop pro and we have recently upgraded them from 2016. When trying to run a report, we are getting a different balance than what is recorded. We then try to Verify through the utilities and we get an error that states, "One of your employees SSN is invalid" "One of your employees DOB is invalid" then it crashes the program. Trying to edit this specific employees info also triggers the errors/crashes the program. I have also tried to export the employee list but errors trigger again seemingly at each outlet I try. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like two different ( and  unrelated issues)

You can try this...

1) Correct the employee issues: Go back to your original 2016 file -- hopefully you can restore it from a backup made prior to the upgrade -- and edit/correct the employees there, then update the file again. Just to verify, try editing the employee again in the updated file... if still an issue, either the original or the update may be (getting) corrupted  during the upgrade, in which case you'll likely need to talk to Intuit's tech support.

2) Balance issues: make sure your comparing the reports with the same 'basis' method, Accrual or Cash, shouldn't matter, but they both must be the same basis.

Good Luck.